# Stored procedures vs standard select update, avoid locks

Tags: sql, locking, sybase, database-locking

In order to retrieve an ID, I first do a select and then an update, in two consequent queries.

The problem is that I am having problems with locked rows. I've read that putting both this statements, Select and Update in one stored procedure it helps with the locks. Is this true?

The queries I run are:

```
select counter 
from dba.counter_list 
where table_name = :TableName

update dba.counter_list 
set counter = :NewCounter 
where table_name = :TableName
```

The problem is that it can happen that multiple users are selecting the same row and also possible that they update the same row.

Comment: Please post your existing code and explain your exact problem with locks.

Comment: @PM77-1 I did, thank you

Comment: Locks are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s it's SQL combined with Delphi.

Comment: **SQL** isn't a database - it's a query language. What **concrete RDBMS** are you using?? Oracle? Mysql? Postgresql? Firebird? Something else?

Comment: @marc_s you are right, sorry. I am using Sybase.

Comment: There are (at least) 4 different RDBMS products under the 'Sybase' name; which product are you using? ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?

Comment: Putting them in one *transaction* would affect locking.  I'm not aware that putting them in a stored procedure would have much effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- you're using Sybase ASE
- your `select` returns a single value for `counter`
- you may want the old `counter` value for some purpose other than performing the update

Consider the following `update` statement which should eliminate any race conditions that may occur with multiple users running your `select/update` logic concurrently:

```
declare @counter int            -- change to the appropriate datatype

update  dba.counter_list
set     @counter = counter,     -- grab current value
        counter  = :NewCounter  -- set to new value
where   table_name = :TableName

select  @counter                -- send previous counter value to client
```

- the `update` obtains an exclusive lock on the desired row (or page/table depending on table design and locking scheme)
- with an exclusive lock in place you're able to retrieve the current value and set the new value with a single statement

---

Whether you submit the above via a SQL batch or a stored proc call is up to you and your DBA to decide ...

- if statement cache is disabled, a SQL batch will need to be compiled each time it's submitted to the dataserver
- if statement cache is enabled, and you submit this SQL batch on a regular basis then there's a chance the previous query plan is still in statement/procedure cache thus eliminating the (costly) compilation step
- if a copy of previous stored proc (query) plan is not in procedure cache then you'll incur the (costly) compilation step when loading a (proc) query plan into procedure cahe
- a stored proc is typically easier to replace in the event of a syntax/logic/performance issue (as opposed to editing, and possibly compiling, a front-end application)
- ... add your (least) favorite argument for SQL batch vs stored proc (vs prepared statement?) vs ??? ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, very nicely put and explained!

Answer (score 0):

Is the table counter_list accessed by multiple clients concurrently ?

The best practices for OLTP is to call a stored procedure that will perform the update logic in one transaction.

Check that the table dba.counter_list has an index on column table_name.
Check also that it is row level locked.